# Log to terminal when QUnit test suite completes?

Tags: javascript, ember-cli, qunit, ember-qunit, testem

When my test suite completes, I need to output some stats, i. e. meta info about tests collected during test execution.

I'm trying this:

```
QUnit.done(() => console.log("some meta info here"))
```

This works when I run tests in the browser.

But when I run tests in the terminal, the `console.log` output is not displayed.

There's probably some debug flag, but it will enable *all* `console.log` messages and pollute the output greatly.

Instead, I need to output one specific message to the terminal, so that it's logged to CI.

PS `console.log` messages sent during test execution seem to make it into the terminal successfully.

PPS Using QUnit in an Ember CLI app, against Chrome headless.

Comment: is the done hook called in headless?
(like, what if you say process.exit(123) or something? (I actually have no idea if you'd have access to process in whatever scope you're in?

Comment: The code is executed in the browser context, I have no access to Node stuff.

Comment: have you tried other log levels? like `console.warn`, `console.debug`? I wouldn't be surprised if log is filtered out of the terminal, cause of how often it's used

Comment: Yes, no result. The official example uses `console.log`: https://api.qunitjs.com/callbacks/QUnit.done

Comment: what file are you putting the QUnit.done() in? I want to give this a go.

Comment: It's an Ember CLI project. The file could be `tests/test-helper.js` for example.

Comment: anything else you can provide?
I added the above line to my test-helper.js, but my linter caught this: ` 'QUnit' is not defined. (no-undef)`, so I wonder if QUnit needs to be imported? / maybe it's not global?

Comment: Can you add a [module `afterEach` hook](https://api.qunitjs.com/QUnit/module) and try to use `console.log` there? Trying to nail down if it's console logs being eaten, or something with the `done()` callback. If you're using Ember (I don't) then maybe you could try using the [Ember.Logger class](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.0/classes/Ember.Logger/methods/log?anchor=log) instead?

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli QUnit must be imported like this: `import QUnit from 'qunit';`.

Comment: @jakerella, I'm starting to think that it's not an issue of QUnit, but rather of the Testem test runner and its integration with QUnit. As for `Ember.Logger`, it uses `console.log` internally and is deprecated.

Comment: Hmm... there is [this bug filed on their github repo](https://github.com/testem/testem/issues/562), but yeah, I'm pretty sure this is outside QUnit since this works in a raw example.

Comment: That bug relates to the browser mode (with a server), my problem is about plain terminal output mode (no server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a tricky one, as I've never had a need to interact with QUnit like, this, but here are my findings each step of the way:

#### Attempt 1:

[image]
That's a weird error, I thought I was passing a callback function :-\

#### Attempt 2:

[image]
After looking up the documentation for `Qunit.log`, I could see I was using it wrong. Switching to console.log shows the beginning message -- but not the ending message.

#### Attempt 3:

[image]
moduleDone will print something at the  end -- but it also prints for every time you use the word `module` (after everything inside finishes running). So, I guess as a hack if QUnit.done never ends up working, you could keep track of the number of modules started, and modules done, make sure every started modules completes, and if that number is 0 at the end, your test suite is done?

#### Attempt 4

[image]
Turns out, this is only actually helpful for if you want to know the outermost module is done, cause it seems like multiple tests don't run in parallel (which is probably better anyway for test stability).

#### Attempt 5

https://github.com/qunitjs/qunit/issues/1308

It looks like an issue with the testem adapter :(